# How to print every all values with its categories

Tags: php, mysql

I have a page that gives me info from database.

Date - notes - account_type

In account_type I have 3 types of account PS: A - B - C.

```
$Qdaily_entriesD = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM daily_entries ORDER BY account_type DESC");
while ($showRowGeneral = mysqli_fetch_assoc($Qdaily_entriesD))
{
?>
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo $showRowGeneral['account_type'];?></td>
      <td><?php echo $showRowGeneral['riyal'];?></td>
      <td><?php echo $showRowGeneral['dollars'];?></td>
    </tr>
<?php
}
```

I want when I print the values it came out with different urls for each account_type.

Like: accounts.php?type=A , B or C

This is what i have tried

```
<?php
$Qdaily_entriesD = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM daily_entries ORDER BY account_type DESC");
while ($showRowGeneral = mysqli_fetch_assoc($Qdaily_entriesD))
{
    if ($showRowGeneral['account_type'] == 'b')
    {
?>
        <tr>
          <td><?php echo $showRowGeneral['account_type'];?></td>
          <td><?php echo $showRowGeneral['riyal'];?></td>
          <td><?php echo $showRowGeneral['dollars'];?></td>
        </tr>
<?php
    }
}
?>
<tr><td colspan='3'><a href='?type=A'>A</a>, <a href='?type=B'>B</a> or <a href='?type=C'>C</a></td></tr>
```

but how to achieve this?
Thanks advanced.

Comment: What have you tried to achieve your wanted results? What has your research concerning your problem shown? Can you provide code of your tries? [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How much research effort is expected](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) might be helpful to improve your question.

Comment: Where do you want this anchor tag to be placed. I dont see one, so you have not even tried to do this for yourself!

Comment: @RiggsFolly no i did have tried but i didn't get the idea! how to achieve this.

Comment: @IrisTako: Are you just asking how to make a link in HTML?  Surely any introductory tutorial covers this?  It's not clear where you're actually stuck.  What have you tried and what didn't work?

Comment: So edit the question and add your attempt to it. Then we can at least see where you want the anchor tag placed

Comment: I have edited my question.

Comment: @IrisTako: It's still not clear what the problem is.  So you have a link: `<a href='?type=A'>` and you want the URL in the link to be "accounts.php?type=A".  So.... this?: `<a href='accounts.php?type=A'>`  What does this have to do with the loop above it?  What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to use `$_GET` ?

Read this for more info https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp

In your code you want to use it like so,

```
if ($showRowGeneral['account_type'] == $_GET['type'])
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have a link for each line :

```
$Qdaily_entriesD = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM daily_entries ORDER BY account_type DESC");
while ($showRowGeneral = mysqli_fetch_assoc($Qdaily_entriesD))
{
?>
<tr>
    <td><?echo $showRowGeneral['account_type'];?></td>
    <td><?echo $showRowGeneral['riyal'];?></td>
    <td><?echo $showRowGeneral['dollars'];?></td>
    <td><a href="<?php echo 'accounts.php?type=' . $showRowGeneral['account_type']; ?>">your text</a></td>
</tr>
<?
}
```